# Checkboxes and table data in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

is there any reason why these table checkboxes would return a '1' or true statement whether they are checked or not?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lake/Body Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="title"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fishing:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="fish"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Wakeboarding:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="wake"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Skiing:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="ski"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tubing:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="tube"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Comments:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="comments"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Save &amp; Close" onclick="saveBoat()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is a content VAR for a google maps infowindow, BTW...

Comment: Return '1' to where? Please explain how you are trying to access the value. On form submission, if checked they should submit the value `'1'`; if unchecked they should not be submitted at all. But if the `value` is accessed via JS it will be `'1'` either way.

Comment: HTML5 does not yet is fully specified, but apart from that, you are not making use of *any* proposed HTML5 features. Please don't tag your HTML related questions with it. Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what Javascript you are using to check for it being "checked". Using `.value` on a checkbox element is not the same as using the `.checked` property. If you see, you are setting the `value` attribute for the checkbox elements in the HTML as `1`. As I said before, this is unrelated to its `checked` state and is accessed differently.

Comment: @HondaKillrsx No problem. It's definitely not the most straightforward thing. Just remember, using `.checked` gets its current state of being checked, while `.value` gets its current value, and both are unrelated...but its `checked` state determines whether it is submitted in a form submission or not. The `.checked` property can be set by clicking on it or by setting it in Javascript, while the `.value` can really only be set with Javascript.